# Flutter invalid Argument when fetching data

Tags: flutter

I am getting this error when trying to fetch data from a Api:

The following ArgumentError was thrown building StreamBuilder(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<String, AsyncSnapshot>#735fb):

Invalid argument(s)

The function causing this problem is **fetchSong()**

This is the Code for fetching and displaying(Commenting out all lines in ui that display data in the ui solves the problem):

```
   class _RadioBarState extends State<RadioBar> {
    Map<String, dynamic> song = {};
    

    fetchSong() async {
      var response = await http.get(
          "https://api.radioking.io/widget/radio/leipzig-beatz/track/current");
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var items = json.decode(response.body);
        setState(
          () {
            song = items;
          },
        );
      }
    }


    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => RadioDetail(),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                    ),
                    child: ListTile(
                      tileColor: Palette.bottomBarColor,
                      title: Text(
                        song['title'] ?? "N/A",
                        style:
                            TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                      ),
                      subtitle: Text(
                        song['album'] ??
                            "N/A" + " \u2219 " + song['artist'] ??
                            "N/A",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14, color: Palette.radioSubtileColor),
                      ),
                      trailing: Consumer<RadioProvider>(
                        builder: (context, data, child) {
                          return CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                            child: IconButton(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              onPressed: () async {
                                await _flutterRadioPlayer.playOrPause();
                              },
                              icon: snapshot.data ==
                                      FlutterRadioPlayer.flutter_radio_playing
                                  ? Icon(Icons.pause)
                                  : Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                      leading: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                          song['cover'] ?? "N/A",
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          StreamBuilder<String>(
            initialData: "",
            stream: _flutterRadioPlayer.metaDataStream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              fetchSong();
              return Container();
            },
          ),
        ]
  }
```

When I comment out all lines in the ui out that takes data from the fetchSong function e.g song['cover'],song['title'] etc. The error disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting "Future" before the fetchSong(), and then in the stream, try change the "String" to "RadioBar" class